# Dockerfile: How to run the ssh server in my container image as non-root user?

Tags: dockerfile

What changes do I need to make to my make Dockerfile run the sshd server as user ssh?

```
FROM alpine:3.15.4
RUN apk add --upgrade --no-cache openssh=8.8_p1-r1 \
    && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN addgroup -S jumper && adduser -S jumper -G jumper
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chown -R jumper:jumper /etc/ssh

USER jumper
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

At the moment I get the error message "/etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied" when starting the container.

The config file is copied in my entry script.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f /config/sshd_config ]; then
    cp /config/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
fi

ssh-keygen -A
exec "$@"
```